# UWP: BackgroundTask open App Mainpage

Tags: win-universal-app, background-task

Is it possible to open my app by my own backgroundtask?

when i have a backgroudtask in windows universal platform, can i start or open my app.mainpage from there? 
my backgroundtask checks periodicaly the clipboard and if it gets an hit, then it should open my app.

does this work with uwp or is uwp again a no-go software ?
any soltutions or ideas therefore?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by a toast. Here is an example.

```
   var content =
        $@"
            <toast activationType='foreground' launch='args'>
                <visual>
                    <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
                        <text>Open app</text>
                        <text>Your clipboard is ready.Open app</text>
                    </binding>
                </visual>
                <actions>

                    <action content='ok' activationType='foreground' arguments='check'/>

                  <action activationType='system' arguments='dismiss' content='cancel' />

                </actions>
            </toast>";


        Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument toastDOM = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
        toastDOM.LoadXml(content);
        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastDOM);
        var notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
        notifier.Show(toast);
```

And then if user press the ok button you must go in App.xaml.cs and handle that

```
 protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.ToastNotification)
        {
            var toastArgs = args as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;
            var arguments = toastArgs.Argument;

            if (arguments == "check")
            {
                Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                if (rootFrame == null)
                {
                    rootFrame = new Frame();
                    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
                }
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(YOURPAGEHERE));
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for that example.
isn't it possible to start the launcher() from the backgrountTask?